# convert lower bitrate mp3 to higher bit rate

Tags: php, ffmpeg

i had 2000 songs in 128 kbps but in my server space was not there so i have compressed those mp3 to 16kbps and found ok quality on my pc but when i was listening those songs on my iphone i found that sound quality is not good so now i wan t to convert those 16kbps songs to 48kbps which i think will give good sound quality so that users cant differentiate that songs are compressed and it will load fast as well .here is the ffmpeg code i have used to convert 16kbps file to 48kbps . i can see that the size of converted file has increased approx 3 fold but not sure whether it will give the better quality mp3 when i increase the bit rate through conversion .please suggest any  way to get my file back with good mp3 quality

```
  <?php  
 if ( exec('ffmpeg  -i /pathtomp3folder/test.mp3  -acodec libmp3lame  -ab 48k -ac 1 -ar 44100  /pathtomp3folder/oputput.mp3'))

   {
  echo 'done!!';
  }

  ?>
```

i can do below code as well wthout specifying the frequency which is best way to do

```
   ffmpeg  -i /pathtomp3folder/test.mp3  -acodec libmp3lame  -ab 48k -ac 1   /pathtomp3folder/oputput.mp3

  {
  echo 'done!!';
   }
```

i dont see much difference in 16kbps and converted file quality however size got increased 3 times in converted file

what is the minimum kbps we should prefer so that users cant detect the difference and i get high streaming rate as well without buffering .i am targetting mobile device so please suggest about mobile device

size of 16 kbps file was 745kb and size of 48kbps file is 1840kb

where i am doing mistake any idea or if anyone can share his experinene it will be a great help .i have stuggled to get my collection of 2000 songs back as i dont have backup and in my pc the quality of mp3 seems to be ok but when i play in iphone it clearly shows that its of low quality

in my server ffmpeg is installed and working properly so it is easily converting the bit rate .one more thing i want to know when the bit rate is getting changed from 16kbps to 48 kbps what is the changes in quality???/ as i can clearly see that size is increasing but the quality remains same

Comment: increasding bitrate, where do you think the extra bits are going to come from?

Comment: Shoulda backed them up.

Comment: Increasing the bitrate isn't going to increase the quality, when you shrunk them you lost the quality permanently as mp3 uses lossy compression.

Comment: For a more elaborate explanation see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression

Comment: Check the floor under your pc. The bits might still be there...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't add quality just by increasing the bitrate. It's like an image - if you have an image that is 24px square, and increase it to 72px it's just going to get blurry. FFMPEG or any other library has no way of knowing what data was removed when you reduced it to 16kbps (if the data was still there you wouldn't get any file size reduction) so it has no way of putting it back.

Only way to get decent 48kbps versions of your files is to convert them down from the higher rate originals. If you don't have access to them any more...consider it a lesson in using backups.

Answer (score 0):

> MPEG-1 or MPEG-2 Audio Layer III, more commonly referred to as MP3, is a patented encoding format for digital audio which uses a form of **lossy data compression**.
>
> The use in MP3 of a lossy compression algorithm is designed to greatly reduce the amount of data required to represent the audio recording and still sound like a faithful reproduction of the original uncompressed audio for most listeners. ... An MP3 file can also be constructed at higher or lower bit rates, with higher or lower resulting quality.

[Mp3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3).

You can increase bitrate but sound would not be better.